# LISTAGG как оконная функция с нарастающим итогом

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужен аналог SUM, но вместо суммы - конкатенация. Например следующий код является рабочим:

```
SELECT sum(num) OVER (ORDER BY num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_total
     , num
  FROM (SELECT level AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 4) t;
```

Ну или просто:

```
SELECT sum(num) OVER (ORDER BY num) AS running_total
     , num
  FROM (SELECT level AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 4) t;
```

Вернется результат:

| RUNNING_TOTAL | NUM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |

А следующий код является не рабочим (хотя среда Intellij Idea ошибки не видит):

```
SELECT listagg(num, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num)
               OVER (ORDER BY num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_total
     , num
  FROM (SELECT level AS num FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 10) t;
```

Вернется непонятная ошибка: "[99999][30487] ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here" (хотя в целом её можно использовать как оконную, но только с PARTITION и без ORDER BY.

Я же хочу получить результат:

| RUNNING_TOTAL | NUM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1,2 | 2 |
| 1,2,3 | 3 |

Как вариант на ум приходит использование функции как агрегирующей. Что-то вроде:

```
  WITH
    cte(num, lvl) AS (SELECT level AS num
                           , 1 AS lvl
                        FROM dual
                     CONNECT BY level <= 3
                       UNION ALL
                      SELECT c.num - 1 AS num
                           , lvl + 1 AS lvl
                        FROM cte c
                       WHERE num - 1 >= 1)
SELECT listagg(cte.num, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num) AS running_total
     , max(num) AS num
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY lvl
 ORDER BY num;
```

Но вопрос в том, можно ли сделать это проще.

Comment: *Вернется непонятная ошибка: "[99999][30487] ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here"* Ну почему.. очень даже понятно. [LISTAGG Function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030) - там чётко пишут, что определение OVER включает только и исключительно query_partition_clause. Сравни с описанием любой другой оконной функции - там имеется дополнительный order_by_clause. То есть никакого ORDER BY у LISTAGG в определении окна нет и быть не может (как и RANGE/ROWS). Хочешь конкатенацию с накоплением - используй рекурсивный CTE. Либо коррелированный агрегирующий подзапрос.

Comment: @Akina, ну непонятна, конечно, не сама ошибка, а то почему разрабы не включили возможность использования накопления как в случае с суммой. Да, пока накостылил рекурсивный CTE, но мне такая ассиметрия не по душе :) Подумалось, может мне образования не хватает сделать элегантнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `listagg` есть `order-by-clause`, просто `order-by` пишется внутри `within group`, а не внутри `over`.
У неё нет `windowing-clause` (где задаётся `range/rows between`).

```
SELECT 
    n, val,
    regexp_substr(
        listagg(val, ',') within group (order by n) over (), 
        '(,?[^,]+){'||n||'}'
    ) as list
FROM
    (SELECT level AS n, 'V'||level as val FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 10) t
order by n;
```

---

> почему разрабы не включили возможность использования накопления как в случае с суммой

Потому что из общей суммы частичную сумму извлечь невозможно. А из общей конкатенации частичную конкатенацию - легко! Вот поэтому и не сделали, чтобы не усложнять реализацию `listagg` ненужными возможностями.

Comment: Лихо придумано, красивое :)